# set background colour for listitem on page render

Tags: android, listview, listitem

I have following layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ShowMessageList">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabMsgDel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/lstMessages"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lstMessages"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMessages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fabMsgDel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, the code behind is

```
package com.example.hp_pc.qc;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class ShowMessageList extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView lstMsgs;
        Cursor cursor, cursorDel;
        String selectedTxt;
        SQLiteDatabase database;
        String[] MessageLists;
        private int selected;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_message_list);
            lstMsgs = findViewById(R.id.lstMessages);

            database = new SampleSQLiteDBHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
            MessageLists = new String[3];
            MessageLists[0] = SampleSQLiteDBHelper.MESSAGE_COLUMN_ID;
            MessageLists[1] = SampleSQLiteDBHelper.MESSAGE_COLUMN_NAME;
            MessageLists[2] = SampleSQLiteDBHelper.MESSAGE_IS_DEFAULT;

            readFromDB();
            //lstMsgs.getChildAt(selected).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            lstMsgs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selected = position;
                    selectedTxt = (String) lstMsgs.getItemAtPosition(selected);
                    View lstMsgsChildAt = lstMsgs.getChildAt(selected);
                    lstMsgsChildAt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            });

            setMessageLst();

        }

        private void setMessageLst() {
            String[] values = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int cnt = 0;
            try {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    values[cnt] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SampleSQLiteDBHelper.MESSAGE_COLUMN_NAME));
                    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SampleSQLiteDBHelper.MESSAGE_IS_DEFAULT)) == 1)
                    {
                        selected = cnt;
                //        lstMsgs.getChildAt(cnt).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                    cnt = cnt + 1;
                }
            }finally {
                cursor.close();
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> msgLSt = new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            lstMsgs.setAdapter(msgLSt);
            lstMsgs.performItemClick(lstMsgs, selected, selected);
          }

        }
```

When I am reaching the `lstMsgs.setOnItemClickListener`, I am getting `null` at `lstMsgs.getChildAt(selected)`. This is getting called after `setMessageLst`.

Can you help me why I am getting `null`. I am trying to set color to one item when the page loads, but I am not getting access to the list item. Let me know if I am  completely off track or missing some small point.

Comment: Can you paste in the actual LogCat message?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have created inner anonymous "AdapterView.OnItemClickListener" inside "ShowMessageList" class. So you can not use any property or method of "ShowMessageList" inside "AdapterView.OnItemClickListener".

To use outerclass property and method, you need below syntex inside inner anonymous class.

```
OuterClassName.this.propertyormethod
```

Please look at below updated code

```
lstMsgs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ShowMessageList.this.selected = position;
        selectedTxt = (String) ShowMessageList.this.lstMsgs.getItemAtPosition(ShowMessageList.this.selected);
        View lstMsgsChildAt = ShowMessageList.this.lstMsgs.getChildAt(ShowMessageList.this.selected);
        lstMsgsChildAt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
});
```